# Replacing parent action of Custormizr theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created my own child theme. Everything works great except I can't seem to unregister a hoook.

$this is class `TC_footer_main`  and the following code is in the `__construct`

```
add_action ( '__colophon'       , array( $this , 'tc_colophon_center_block' ), 20 );
```

I tried several remove actions with no success. I am just trying to change/remove the footer:

`remove_action( '__colophon' , 'tc_colophon_center_block' , 55);`

or

`remove_action( '__colophon' , array('TC_footer_main','tc_colophon_center_block') , 55);`

I've also tried

`remove_action( '__colophon' , TC_footer_main::$instance->tc_colophon_center_block() , 55);`

But that threw an error as `TC_footer_main` was not loaded by the time my `functions.php` file ran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am just trying to change/remove the footer:

I think you're making it way more complex, to modify the output of the `tc_colophon_center_block()` method, than it has to be.

Just use the `tc_credits_display` filter:

```
add_filter( 'tc_credits_display', function( $html )
{
    // Modify output to your needs!
    return $html;
} );
```

to modify that block to your needs.

To totally remove the output (if that's allowed), simply use:

```
add_filter( 'tc_credits_display', '__return_null', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

You have further access  to filters like:

- `tc_copyright_link`
- `tc_credit_link`
- `tc_wp_powered`

to choose from.

That's it!

Comment: ps: I'm not an affiliate but looks like the pro version gives you the ability to modify the footer directly via the Customizer setup.

Comment: Thank you, I can change the header myself but I wanted the best practice on doing so. And not by hardcoding in the parent theme

Answer (score 3):

For your purpose add the following code in function.php. It will get call on after_setup_theme hook.

```
// replace parent function
function child_theme_function () {
    // your code goes here
 }

function my_theme_setup () {
    remove_action( '__colophon', 'tc_colophon_center_block', 1000 );
    add_action( '__colophon', 'child_theme_function', 1000 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_setup' );
```

You can also try for overriding the parent class from child class as described   here:  https://thethemefoundry.com/tutorials/advanced-customization-replacing-theme-functions/

Comment: Your solution only got me halfway there. I was able to output my footer but not remove the old one. That's because its within a class. `TC_footer_main`

Comment: To remove the old one you can use:
    <?php 
     remove_action( 'widgets_init', 'parenttheme_widgets_init' );

     function childtheme_widgets_init() {
    /* Some code to register widget areas goes here */
    }
   add_action( 'widgets_init', 'childtheme_widgets_init' );
?>

For more reference please check at: http://benpearson.com.au/replace-a-non-pluggable-function-in-a-wordpress-parent-theme-with-a-customized-function-in-the-child-theme/

Answer (score 2):

you werent too far away...one problem you may have is you are trying to remove the hook before it has been added by your parent theme..the class could be initialized at a later stage...

im not too sure when your hook runs, but hopefully its after init

```
 add_action('init', 'remove_parent_hook');

 function remove_parent_hook(){
      remove_action( '__colophon' , array('TC_footer_main','tc_colophon_center_block') , 20); // needs to be the same priority
 }
```

you can obviously now just add a action for your new function.

There is a offchance that a anonymous function has been added, often the significance of `&$this` is overlooked when trying to remove a hooked function. This is a pain because wp will assign a random string as the key name & the function name for the function, its different every time so it cant be guessed. But we can search for the function name within the key so something like this will work

```
    function remove_anon_hk($hook, $function, $priority=10 ){

        global $wp_filter;

        $hooks= $wp_filter[$hook][$priority];

        if(empty ($hooks))
            return;

        foreach($hooks as $hk=>$data):
            if(stripos($hk, $function) !== false ){
                unset($wp_filter[$hook][$priority][$hk]);
            }
        endforeach;
    }


    add_action('init', function(){
        remove_anon_hk('__colophon', 'tc_colophon_center_block');
    });
```